# Microsoft Graph API Send Mail Response Is Empty

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to send an email using modern smtp with Office365 Graph API. Emails are sending fine, with attachments however, I cannot seem to fullfill the response I'm expecting from the endpoint.

```
$this->graphSdk->createRequest("POST", "/users/" . $this->config['from_email'] . "/sendmail")
    ->attachBody($this->getMessageBody($message))
    ->setReturnType(Message::class)
    ->execute()
```

The response when I dump and die is the following (the email successfully sends and I receive it):

```
Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message {#4623
  #_propDict: []
}
```

I need to obtain both the message ID and conversation ID from this but I cannot seem to find any source of help from the documentation other than adding the associated return type which I have as the expected `Message`, any help appreciated.

Update: I am using Laravel 8.x, I have attempted to attach a custom listener to the message but it does not contain any details that match the O365 details (ie, the Swift Message object ID is ignored by O365 and replaced with one of their own).

Comment: Note that the action is spelled [`sendMail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), not `sendmail`.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph API does not return the message object or any response by default. It returns a `202 Accepted` status code.

Microsoft Graph PHP SDK sucks ! not documented .. lack of information...

Comment: Does the Graph API utilise the Message ID that the Switft Message created? Can I use that same ID to send another request to Graph API to load the message details?